# How to give potential employers the opportunity to see my academic work?

Tags: resume, job-search, internship

My general question is, given that you have written some *unpublished* research papers as part of your academic coursework (on own topics, however) that you put extra amount of effort into and would like to show off to potential employers, how would you go about including these in applications?

To give some more specific context: As part of my mathematics course I had to write two papers on my own topic of interest. As I was more interested (and effectively better) in the subject than the other students I put a lot of extra hours to solve two original and quite difficult math problems. They are both in a professional format (written in LaTeX) and they showcase my ability to write a formal proof.

Now, as a first-year undergraduate, I am looking around for internships, and a lot of positions that I'm applying for list "a strong mathematical background" as a preferred or minimal requirement for their job. I feel like these papers would potentially be an excellent way for me to exhibit my "mathematical background", but unless they have been published, I don't see a conventional way of showcasing them or linking to them in my CV or cover letter.

Is there a way in which I could guide recruiters to these papers without it seeming over-the-top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question as written: you just put a link on your CV. Something like

> 2016 - 2019 (expected): BA, Mathematics, Really Impressive University
>
> Courses include complex analysis, vector algebra and sheep herding. Some examples of my work can be found here (add link).

However, unless you're applying for some *really* specialised internships, "evidence of mathematical ability" is almost certainly fulfilled just by doing a degree course in maths so you don't need to over think this one.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I want to include these mostly because I think they may put me at an advantage, and not because I think the employer will have doubts about my mathematical abilities.

I just have a pretty trivial inquiry about your answer: do you know of a website adequate for uploading unpublished scientific works?

Comment: Also, how did you know that we have a course in sheep herding at RI University?

Answer (score 1):

I would add them to your CV under publications, mention them in your cover letter and attach them along with your CV and cover letter.